# UniformTypeIdentifiers UTType always returns null

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mime-types

I'm trying to get Mime type from downloaded file path.

```
            var fileNanager = new NSFileManager();
            if (!fileNanager.FileExists(path))
            {
                return null;
            }

            var uti = UniformTypeIdentifiers.UTType.GetType(Path.GetExtension(path), UniformTypeIdentifiers.UTTagClass.FilenameExtension, null);
            var x = uti?.PreferredMimeType;

            if (x == null)
            {
                return "application/octet-stream";
            }
            return x;
```

Even though there's a PDF file path uti is always null and I can only get result "application/octet-stream" instead of "application/pdf".
What did I do wrong?

Comment: You can first try to debug the program by using break points to see if the type of ‘uti’ is correct.

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT Thanks for your suggestion. I figured it out so I posted an answer for this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UniformTypeIdentifiers.UTType.GetType` requires file extension without '.' while `Path.GetExtension(path)` returns a file extension with '.' included.

Removing '.' in advance does the trick.